# CRUD, Verbs, and Actions in Rails 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

While working with rails 5.0.1, I had a Subjects controller with a Subject Model, but while trying to use

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= subject.position %></td>
  <td><%= subject.name %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
  <td class="actions">
    <%= link_to("Show", subject_path(subject.id), :class => 'action show') %>
    <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
    <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I got a method not found error on this line.

```
subject_path(subject.id)
```

On further research, I noticed in rails 5.0.1, the index resource was removed and somehow replaced by the show, I also confirmed it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource). Please is there a way around this, I need how to display a list of resources (resource#index) and also show specific item on the list (resource#show)

Comment: could you provide your routes.rb? I think you might be using `resource` instead of `resources` while wanting the second one

Comment: wow, wow, wow, thanks alot, i used resource, can you please explain the difference

Comment: best would be just to see it here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong method in your routes.

`resource` is meant for [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources). Meaning cases  where there only ever can be one  of the resource.

What you want is `resources`.

```
resources :subjects
# this would generate routes for an app wide configuration
resource :configuration
```

When routing to objects you can just pass the record itself:

```
# bad
subject_path(subject.id)
# good
subject_path(subject)
# better
link_to("Show", subject, class: 'action show')
```

Since this calls `#to_param` on the model it makes it trivial to setup stuff like friendly urls later on and is considered a good practice.

Comment: The change in Rails 5 makes sense. Having an index of something there only can be one of is just wrong.